# Will a SONY micro-usb to USB cable work as PWR In on my Raspberry Pi Zero W?

Tags: pi-zero-w

I recently bought a RP ZERO W board and now I am looking around the house to see if I have a cable that can power it up from the computer.

I found this: [https://www.amazon.com/Genuine-Original-Sony-EC450-Charging/dp/B00BBVGHD6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BBVGHD6)

A sony ec450 charger that I use my Android phone. My question now is if this cable would also work to power a RP Zero W by inserting it to the PWR In port and then to my computer.

I am new to raspberry so I do not want risk any components/computer getting damaged before I try it.

Comment: Yes. It should work just fine.

Comment: Ok, could it potentially damage anything if the voltage/something else is wrong?

Comment: The voltage will always be 5v over USB, whether it be plugged into a computer or a wall outlet. Unless the cable is frayed and/or has shorts, it'll be fine. If it works fine with your phone, it'll work fine here too.

Answer (score 1):

In fact it may or may **NOT** work.

Generally computer USB ports provide insufficient current to operate a Pi. You may get away with 500mA on a Pi Zero W, even though this is below the recommended current.

The next variable is the computer. If it has a standards compliant port it will only supply 100mA without negotiation. The Pi **CANNOT** negotiate, because the power port has no data connection.

MacBooks do comply, although many of the cheaper laptops just provide 5V with no control.

> In short you need a proper power supply. You also need a decent cable; most **Charger** cables should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

The Pi usually takes at around 350 mA when not overclocked. If your cable can constantly deliver a power of at least 1 A, it should work fine. As long as the inner resistance of the cable isn't  too high, also peaks in current should be no problem.

I am asking myself why you are asking that. As far as I know there is no official Pi cable, so you **have** to use one of yours.

Comment: thanks for the answer!! yeah the reason iam asking because I am brand new to the raspberry world and i was just a bit confused on what cables would work and what cables wouldnt